# Run javascript node module in rails on server side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js

Is it any way to run Node packages through Rails 5.x on server side? ExecJS can't  use CommonJS require(), whereas CommonJS isn't supported and don't work even with Rails 4.x. Thanks in advance for every answer.